# Angular Seed::Example use of controllers

Tags: angularjs

The [seed app](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed) uses routes, which reference controllers, and the controllers are defined like this:

```
function MyCtrl1() {} 
MyCtrl1.$inject = [];
```

Looking for a better example (ie) showing injection, maybe an HTTP get and update to scope?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you want, but here is a more complex example.

**Controller:**

```js
function MyCtrl1 ( $scope, $http ) {
  $http.get( '/some/location' ).success( function ( data ) {
    $scope.items = data;
  });
}
MyCtrl1.$inject = [ '$http' ];
```

**View:**

```html
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl1">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.name}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Commentary:**

In a real world scenario, the $http calls would be in your own service that would be injected into the controller instead. Also, I recommend against defining controllers in the global space. A better way to define the same controller would be like this:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller( 'MyCtrl', [ '$http', function MyCtrl1 ( $scope, $http ) {
  $http.get( '/some/location' ).success( function ( data ) {
    $scope.items = data;
  });
}]);
```

**Update:**

Controllers are useless without a scope - the really couldn't do anything - so Angular automatically injects $scope into every controller. Every other service must be requested to be injected. The `MyCtrl1.$inject` and the array syntax are both only necessary to still remain functional after minification. If you create a sample file with my code and delete the `$inject` line, it will still work. But when you minify the Javascript, variables names get reduced, so we put the important information in strings.

I recommend going through the [tutorial](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial)  as well as watching some of the videos on the [AngularJS YouTube channel](http://www.youtube.com/user/angularjs/videos?view=0), like [this one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k4qVkWh1EAo).

Comment: What does inject give you that automagic dependency injection does not?  IE why inject $http but not $scope?  Put another way, why is it that in your example above, $scope is magically injected but $http is not?  How would you determine when inject is needed?

Comment: ... and the seed app services example is equally terse:  angular.module('myApp.services', []).
  value('version', '0.1');

Comment: @rob I updated my reply to answer your further questions. Let me know if you have more.

Comment: Why                                 angular.module('myApp.controllers', []).
  controller('MyCtrl1', [function() {

  $scope.greeting={text:"Angular"};  

  }])
  .controller('MyCtrl2', [function() {

  }]);  where I cant access scope in <div ng-controller="MyCtrl1">
{{greeting.text}}
</div>